# HTML Table with 1 shrinking column and multiple fixed width columns with text input

Tags: html

I have an HTML table where column 1 is product name and the other columns 2-6 are price, quantity etc which are all numerical. Table's own with is 100%.

Each cell has an input element for data entry.

The columns 2-6 width should always match content, price,quantity etc must be visible at all times. I expect these fields to grow/shrik as user types in values.

Column 1 (name) is text. As far as I am concerned its content can be wrapped and shrinked to width of 1px.

How can I create such a table? I just got more confused after googling for an hour.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n682xeru/2/. Entering values in quantity column does not cause the column to grow.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border=1 style="width: 100%;">
      <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%"><input style="width:100%" type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       ></td>
        <td><input style="width:100%" type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="1" maxlength="16" value="100"></td>
        <td> <input style="width:100%" type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="1" maxlength="16" value="22444444423423"></td>
        <td><input style="width:100%" type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="1" maxlength="16" value="10%"></td>
        <td>160</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input style="width:100%" type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       ></td>
        <td><input style="width:100%" type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="1" maxlength="16" value="10000.000"></td>
        <td style="min-width: min-content;"><input style="width:100%" type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="1" maxlength="16" value="4"></td>
        <td><input style="width:100%" type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="1" maxlength="16" value="10%"></td>
        <td>16000.000</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you already have a table, you should post your code here (HTML and CSS)

Comment: You do not need to do anything special for this since the numerical values do not contain any word breaking character... longer names will force the price columns to shrink after which the name splits onto multiple rows. If the problem is something else then post HTML markup.

Comment: Thanks Salman. The problem is becomes visible when I add input text fields to columns. I've updated the question with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set table width to 100% and td width will calculate automatically. Then you can set width to td tag witch you want fixed.

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
<table border=1 style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 30px">d</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```